# Extending LMarker in Vue2Leaflet

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet, vue-component

I'm trying to extend a vue.js component ([`LMarker`](https://github.com/KoRiGaN/Vue2Leaflet/blob/master/src/components/LMarker.vue) from Vue2Leaflet) to get it to do two things:

1. Store extra identifying information about the marker
2. Emit a custom event that the parent component can use to display information relevant to the marker that are pulled from the server

The code below is what I have:

```
<template>
  <div style="display: none;">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import LMarker from 'vue2-leaflet'

  export default {
    name: 'LocalityMarker',
    extends: LMarker,
    props: {
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      }

    },
    data: function () {
      return {
        number: 678
      }
    },
    methods: {
      updateLocality: function () {
        this.$emit('marker-clicked', this.number)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

However, this does not work. When I view the component using Vue Devtools, I see the properties defined in LocalityMarker, but not those in LMarker.

The Vue.js docs don't go deep into explaining how [`extends`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#extends) actually works, so I can't tell what I'm doing wrong.

Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i have a solution about your custom marker. I don't extend it but i create a other component will be manipulated by parent.
i don't know exactly what do you want but if you wanna make a marker that receive extra information and display that information; i hope that i wrote anything to help you. Sorry for my writting ( i know, i'm so bad ).
**this parent component**

```
<template lang="pug">
  div
    l-map( :zoom="zoom" :center="center" style="height:500px")
      l-tile-layer( :url="url" , :attribution="attr" )
       div( v-for="marker in markers")
        custome(  ref="cada" ,  :coordinateLL="marker" , :information="'hola que tal;)'")
    button( @click="cambio" ) Se ve?
</template>

<script>
import { LMap, LTileLayer, LMarker, LIcon} from "vue2-leaflet"
import custome from "./protoV2.vue"

export default{
  name:"Proto",
  components:{
    LMap, LTileLayer, LMarker, LIcon, custome
  },
  data (){
    return {
        visible: true,
        url: "http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
        attr: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
        zoom : 2,
        center: [0,0],
        markers: [ [ 46.1222, -12.222 ], [ 46.1222, 12.222 ]  ],
    }
  },
  methods : {
      cambio: function(){
        for( let idx = 0; idx < this.$refs["cada"].length; idx++ ){
            this.$refs["cada"][idx].IsVisible( "gg" );
        }
      }
    }
 };
 </script>
```

**children component**

```
<template >
  <div >
    <l-marker :lat-lng="coordinate"  >
      <slot v-if="visible">
        <l-tooltip :content="message" :options= "{ permanent: true}"  />
      </slot>
    </l-marker>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { LMarker, LPopup, LTooltip } from "vue2-leaflet";

  export default{
  name: "custome",
  components:{
     LMarker, LPopup, LTooltip
  },
  props: {
     coordinateLL : {
         type : Array,
         require : true
     },
     information : {
         type : String,
         require: true
     }
  },
  beforeMount: function(){
        this.coordinate = L.latLng( this.coordinateLL );
  },
  methods: {
      IsVisible: function( msg ){
          this.visible = !this.visible;
      }
  },
  data () {
      return {
         visible: true,
         coordinate: null,
         message: this.information,
         activa: false
      }
  }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue is that you're importing the whole vue2-leaflet package instead of just LMarker. If you throw a debugger in after your import and examine the LMarker object you'll see something like

```
{L: {…}, findRealParent: ƒ, propsBinder: ƒ, LCircle: {…}, LCircleMarker: {…}, …}
```

You can import just LMarker by changing your import line to `import { LMarker } from 'vue2-leaflet';`.